# Reading Data from Text File to a CheckedListBox

Tags: c#

Hallo There
was hopng I could ask for some advice.
Which would be the best way to read data from a textFile and adding this to a checkedListBox?

something like this although this doesn't work out properly.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("../../Features.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs);
            fs.Close();

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("../../Features.txt");


            chkFeatures.Items.Add(sr.ReadToEnd());
            sr.Close();
```

Regards
Arian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
string filePath = @"C:\test.txt";
if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
   checkedListBox1.Items.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filePath));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("../../Features.txt"))
{
    while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
    {
        chkFeatures.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

---

Refer to:

[StreamReader.ReadLine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx)

[StreamReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)